# Using integrated security to connect to SQL Server DB from Spark session

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a regular job that runs on a DataProc cluster, one of the steps involves connecting to a client's SQL Server DB to pull some data. We have been provided a SQL Login and password for this.

I'm told they are changing their security policies to only allow connection via integrated security, but I am unsure how to determine what user actually runs these jobs, or how to set it up so it uses integrated security.

Any help would be much appreciated, let me know if I need to provide more detail.